Combinatorical identity $\sum_{k = d-i}^d (-1)^{k-d+i} \binom{k}{d-i} \cdot \binom{n}{d-k} = \binom{n-d+i-1}{i}$
How do we proove the following ugly identity of binomial coefficients?
$$\sum_{k = d-i}^d (-1)^{k-d+i} \binom{k}{d-i} \cdot \binom{n}{d-k} = \binom{n-d+i-1}{i}$$
First I thought we could use Vandermonde's identity but the alternation of this identity seems to mix things up...

Here we have Vandermonde's identity in disguise.

We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{k=d-i}^{d}}&\color{blue}{(-1)^{k-d+i}\binom{k}{d-i}\binom{n}{d-k}}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^i(-1)^k\binom{k+d-i}{k}\binom{n}{i-k}\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^i\binom{-d+i-1}{k}\binom{n}{i-k}\tag{2}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{n-d+i-1}{i}}\tag{3}
\end{align*}
and the claim follows.

Comment:

In (1) we shift the index to start with $k=0$.

In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.

In (3) we apply Vandermonde's identity.



We need to find
$$\begin{align}
(-1)^{d-i} \sum\limits_k (-1)^{k} \binom{k}{d-i} \binom{n}{d-k}
\end{align}$$
Let's substitute $\binom{n}{d-k} = [x^{d}]x^k (1+x)^n$:
$$
(-1)^{d-i} [x^d](1+x)^n\sum\limits_k \binom{k}{d-i}(-x)^k
$$
Let's use a standard expansion $\frac{x^t}{(1-x)^{t+1}} = \sum\limits_{k} \binom{k}{t} x^k$:
$$
(-1)^{d-i} [x^d] \frac{(1+x)^n (-x)^{d-i}}{(1+x)^{d-i+1}}=[x^i] (1+x)^{n-d+i-1} = \binom{n-d+i-1}{i}.
$$

What do you mean by your substitution? What is $x$ in this case? Why is there a polynomial on the right hand side and a binomial coefficient on the left hand side?

$x$ here is a formal variable. On the right hand side is not a polynomial, but rather a coefficient extraction. $[x^k] p(x)$ is a notation for "coefficient near $x^k$ of $p(x)$". So, I'm just saying that $\binom{n}{d-k}$ is the coefficient near $x^d$ in $x^k (1+x)^n$. Then, the remaining part mostly just uses linearity of coefficient extraction.

Recognizing that
$$
\binom k{d-i}=\binom{k}{k-d+i}=\binom{-k+(k-d+i)-1}{k-d+i}
(-1)^{k-d+i}=\binom{i-d-1}{k-d+i}
(-1)^{k-d+i}
$$
this appears to be indeed Vandermonde's identity.
